# How to get an element's background to show its parent background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

[This image](https://www.breathingcolor.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/BC-ArtofCropping-Cover.jpg) shows what I'm trying to do. There's a parent div with a background image set, and a low opacity. But the child div within the parent div 'resets' the opacity, giving the effect of shining a spotlight on the parent's background image.

How can I do this?

In https://jsfiddle.net/mmik4/3qjepLkm/43/ there's an outline of the code. You can drag the inner div around. How can you create the effect of the image above?

```
#container {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/235270/BackgroundPattern54Multicolour.png');
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: move;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I though about using box-shadow, and for my surprise, it works pretty well.

```
  box-shadow: 0 0 20000px 20000px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mu6ask6c/

Comment: This!  I improved it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/87vaodax/) to make the parent clip the shadow, and to remove the gradient of the shadow.  It looks awesome.  Very clever idea, @zearthur99

Comment: It's looking good. Do you know how to make it work when the 2 components are siblings rather than nested? Please see https://jsfiddle.net/mmik4/87vaodax/6/.

Comment: @user779159 Yes you need to move a few constraints to the parent element, instead: https://jsfiddle.net/uudfv0ou/1/  It would be an idea to confine the position of the 'spotlight square' so it cannot leave its arena when moving it otherwise you can see the edge of the box shadow.  Alternatively you can have an oversized box shadow - but I'm not certain if rendering performance is affected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can increase the opacity of a lower layer by anything you do with a layer above it.

What I think you'll have to do is have the background at full opacity and brightness, then have four divs, each translucent black or gray, which fit together to leave an opening between them where the full-brightness image shows through.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is setting the backgound image in two divs with different levels of brightness inside a container, and using outline instead of border so you don't mess the alignment of the two images.

```
 <div id=container>
  <div id=element></div>
  <div id=shade></div>
</div>


#container {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#shade {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/235270/BackgroundPattern54Multicolour.png');
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: move;
  outline: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  background: url('https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/235270/BackgroundPattern54Multicolour.png');
  filter: brightness(100%);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/53t9k3j3/

Comment: I've updated the link to the jsfiddle where you can drag around the box. In the solution you gave when you drag the box the background of the bright inner box doesn't change.

Comment: Looks like you need to use `background-position` so that the element is positioned correctly. When OP moves the image, be sure that it is set to negative of the offset (plus outline width).